# Error loading pickle file created with Python 2.7 in Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a pickle file which contains floating-point values. This file was created with Python 2.7. In Python 2.7 I used to load it like:

```
matrix_file = pickle.load(open('matrix.pickle', 'r'))
```

Now in Python 3.8 this code is giving error

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

When I trid with 'rb' I got this error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So I tried another method

```
matrix_file = pickle.load(open('matrix.pickle', 'r', encoding='utf-8'))
```

Now I get a different error

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

**Update**: When I try loading with joblib, I get this error

```
ValueError: You may be trying to read with python 3 a joblib pickle generated with python 2. This feature is not supported by joblib.
```

Comment: `'rb'` is definitely required.  Are you sure that the `UnicodeDecodeError` came from unpickling, and not something immediately after?

Comment: Yes. I have been using this file for years in Python 2, never faced an issue.

Comment: You can try to load it with joblib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file must be opened in binary mode *and* you need to provide an `encoding` for the `pickle.load` call. Typically, the `encoding` should either be `"latin-1"` (for pickles with `numpy` arrays, `datetime`, `date` and `time` objects, or when the strings were logically Latin-1), or `"bytes"` (to decode Python 2 `str` as `bytes` objects). So the code should be something like:

```
with open('matrix.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    matrix_file = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin-1')
```

This assumes it was originally containing `numpy` arrays; if not, `"bytes"` might be the more appropriate encoding. I also used a `with` statement just for good form (and to ensure deterministic file closing on non-CPython interpreters).